# Action of Pauli matrices after change of basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, ising-model

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be the Pauli matrices represented by
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}0&1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&-i \\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad Z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}. $$
In general, in the computational basis $\{|0\rangle=(1,0)^T, |1\rangle=(0,1)^T\}$ we say that $X$ implements the bit-flip, while $Z$ implements the phase-flip, as
$$X|0\rangle=|1\rangle, \quad X|1\rangle=|0\rangle $$
while
$$Z|0\rangle=|0\rangle, \quad Z|1\rangle=-|1\rangle. $$
Consider a model such as the Ising model described by $$H=\sum_j X_jX_{j+1}+\sum_j Z_j.$$
What would happen  if we swapped the roles of $X$ and $Z$, writing $$H=\sum_j Z_j Z_{j+1}+\sum_j X_j$$ instead? Would it be correct to say that now the bit-flip is induced by the matrix $Z$?

Comment: The commutation relations of these three Pauli matrices are invariant under Z→X, X→-Z, Y→Y, which is how your hamiltonian transformed. So you have found a new, equivalent, matrix representation for your operators, and your answer is yes. Can you find the similarity transformation achieving this basis change? Wikipedia all but has it.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry, I am a bit confused: aren't we always writing, for example, $$X=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ for the matrix X, regardless of the fact that we have swapped $X$ and $Z$ in the Hamiltonian? This always acts as a bit-flip, doesn't it?

Comment: See my answer. In the new, primed basis, that matrix is not a bit-flipper anymore. Check it explicitly.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ah, from your answer I think I get what confused me. We _define_ the computational basis as the eigenstates of $Z$, but in the new basis, $Z$ is swapped with $X$ so the computational basis is spanned by $\{(1,1)^T, (1,-1)^T\}$ (normalized). So it is now $Z$ that does the flip, while $X$ introduces a phase.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  A mere rotation.

Comment: @CosmasZachos If you don't mind, I have a follow-up question. In the actual Ising model, do we put bit-flips or phase-flips in the interaction term? To clarify: the Hamiltonian should be $$H=J\sum_j Z_jZ_{j+1}-g\sum_j X_j $$ with $Z_j, Z_{j+1}$ representing phase-flips (so, not as if we started from $X_jX_{j+1}$ and rotated), or the opposite?

Comment: That's just it: the difference between bit flip and phase flip is a matter of basis; you may always go to the basis which converts one into the other.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Of course, it was a silly question. I keep fixing in my mind the standard basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ so $Z$ is obviously the phase-flip. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a clockwise rotation by π/2 around the y axis, which brings *X,Y,Z* to
$$
X'=Z\\
Z'=-X\\
Y'=Y, 
$$
and your hamiltonian to your operator-swapped one.

- Note the automorphism of the Lie algebra of the Pauli matrices under this transformation (rotation). That is to say, $(X,Y,Z)\to (X',Y',Z')$ preserves the form of the commutators, so you may use the swapped matrices to represent your operators after the reinterpretation/swap.

So, yes, the primed basis bit-flip is representable by the matrix *Z* you wrote.

The eigenstates of the three matrices are given in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues) on Pauli matrices. In the new basis, the matrix $X'=Z$ indeed flips $(1,1)^T$ to $(1,-1)^T$ and vice versa.